# RxSwift - Receive the same event at two ViewControllers at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Hi i'm just getting started with RxSwift and decided to make simple Currency Exchange application. My app has two view's (allCurrenciesList and userFavouritesView). Basically all logic works, but only if i run networking func every single time one of view didAppear/didLoad. My point is two fetch it only once, and received many times, when necessary.  Application fetch dictionary of currencies and in ViewModel pass it to BehaviorSubject, and when view being load/appear it just subscribe it, and use it in UITableView. Thanks

```
class ListViewModel {
    
    let service: CurrencyService!
    var curriencies = BehaviorRelay<[Currency]>(value: [])
    var currienciesObservable: Observable<[Currency]> {
        return curriencies.asObservable().share()
    }
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
 
    init(service: CurrencyService) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    func fetchAllCurrencies() {
      
            self.service.fetchAllSymbols { result in
                switch result{
                case .success(let currencies):
                    self.dictionaryIntoArray(currencies: currencies["symbols"] as! [String : Any])
                case .failure:
                    print("error")
                    
                }
            }
    }
    
    private func dictionaryIntoArray(currencies: [String: Any]) {
        var currencyArray = [Currency]()
        for (symbol, name) in currencies {
            currencyArray.append(Currency(symbol: symbol, fullName: name as! String))
        }
        let sortedArray = currencyArray.sorted { $0.fullName < $1.fullName }
        self.curriencies.accept(sortedArray)
    }
```

allCurrenciesList

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        configureTableViewDataSource()
        tableView.delegate = self
        fetchData()
    }
    
    private func fetchData() {
        viewModel.fetchAllCurrencies() // this func is necceserry everysingle time 
        viewModel.currienciesObservable.subscribe(onNext: { curriencies in
            self.applySnapshot(curriencies: curriencies)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

userFavouritesView

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        viewModel.fetchAllCurrencies() // this func is necceserry everysingle time 
        viewModel.currienciesObservable.subscribe(onNext: { allCurencies in
            let selectedItems = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "SelectedCells") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
            var currenciesArray: [Currency] = []
            selectedItems.forEach { int in
                self.pickerValues.append(allCurencies[int])
                currenciesArray.append(allCurencies[int])
            }
            self.applySnapshot(curriencies: currenciesArray)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to not use a Subject. They aren't recommended for regular use. Just define the `currienciesObservable` directly.

Something like this:

```
class ListViewModel {
    let currienciesObservable: Observable<[Currency]>

    init(service: CurrencyService) {
        self.currienciesObservable = service.rx_fetchAllSymbols()
            .map { currencies in
                currencies["symbols"]?.map { Currency(symbol: $0.key, fullName: $0.value as! String) }
                    .sorted(by: { $0.fullName < $1.fullName }) ?? []
            }
    }
}

extension CurrencyService {
    func rx_fetchAllSymbols() -> Observable<[String: [String: Any]]> {
        Observable.create { observer in
            self.fetchAllSymbols { result in
                switch result {
                case let .success(currencies):
                    observer.onNext(currencies)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case let .failure(error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

With the above, every time you subscribe to the `currenciesObservable` the fetch will be called.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it's because your `fetchAllSymbols` function was not stored in the DisposeBag.

```
func fetchAllCurrencies() {
    self.service.fetchAllSymbols { result in
         switch result{
            case .success(let currencies):
                self.dictionaryIntoArray(currencies: currencies["symbols"] as! [String : Any])
            case .failure:
                print("error")
                
         }
    }.dispose(by: disposeBag)
}
```